# How can i create a registration form in django which sent mail also

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I'm creating a registration form in `Django` which has `first_name, last_name, email, password` fields. After the registration, all the details are stored in a Database. Meantime I receive an email with all the details. I didn't understand how to execute this .

Comment: please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask show us what you already tried...

Answer (score 2):

Hey you can send the mail after form.save() method.

```
 def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    performing post request and marking the user object as active and
    sending the registration email to the user email account
    """
    form = self.form(data=request.data)
    if form.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        user = form.save()
        ## you can define your method to send the mail call after save
        account_utils.send_user_registration_email(user)
    return
```

Comment: If we have four fields and need to store all data in the database and email id should not be duplicate.
I this condition is this working...\

Comment: that will be get validated in form clean method

Comment: I created email function but I need to send the email which email addresses define in the signup form. is there any way